# Ruby : Simple Calculator using THOR to provide values at terminal. Error:`add': uninitialized constant MyCLI::Simplecal (NameError)

Tags: ruby, thor

I have two "rb" files:
SimpleCal.rb,
cli.rb

SimpleCal.rb->Code

```
class SimpleCal

#adding two numbers
  def addition_function(n1,n2)
      n1 + n2
  end
#subtracting two numbers (Validation:n2 shouldn't be greater than n1)
  def subtract_function(n1,n2)
    if n1<n2
      puts "Error:Negative"
    else
      n1 - n2
    end
  end
#multiplication (Validation:n1 & n2 shouldn't be 0)
  def multiplication_function(n1,n2)
    if n1 == 0 || n2 == 0
      puts "Warning:Result will be zero"
    else
      n1 * n2
    end
  end
#divison (Validation:n2 shouldn't be 0)
  def division_function(n1,n2)
    if n2 == 0
      puts "Warning:Division by zero"
    else
      n1 / n2
    end
  end
end
```

Description:
I am trying to provide method functions for simple calculator along with validations.

clir.rb -> Code (thor)

```
require 'thor'
require 'SimpleCal'


class MyCLI < Thor
  desc "add", "Addition of two numbers"
  #making use of options to provide values in terminal to add
  option:n1, :type => :numeric
  option:n2, :type => :numeric
  #thor:add command(should call the method "addtion function from SimpleCal.rb" and add the values provided through "options" in terminal)
   def add
     puts "n1: #{options[:n1]}"
     puts "n2: #{options[:n2]}"

     obj = SimpleCal.new

     res = obj.addition_function(options[:n1],options[:n2])

     puts "Addtion ->#{res}"
   end
   def mul
     puts "n1: #{options[:n1]}"
     puts "n2: #{options[:n2]}"

     obj = SimpleCal.new

     res = obj.multiplication_function(options[:n1],options[:n2])

     puts "Multiplication ->#{res}"
   end
   def sub
     puts "n1: #{options[:n1]}"
     puts "n2: #{options[:n2]}"

     obj = SimpleCal.new

     res = obj.subtract_function(options[:n1],options[:n2])

     puts "Subtract ->#{res}"
   end
   def div
     puts "n1: #{options[:n1]}"
     puts "n2: #{options[:n2]}"

     obj = SimpleCal.new

     res = obj.subtract_function(options[:n1],options[:n2])

     puts "Divison ->#{res}"
   end

end

MyCLI.start(ARGV)
```

Description:
cli.rb file should call the method functions from SimpleCal.rb file to perform simple calculator functions. The values for Calculator should be passed through terminal by making use of "options"
Expected Output:
ruby cli mul --n1 2 --n2 3
n1: 2
n2: 3
Multiplication: 6

ERROR:

```
./cli.rb:15:in `add': undefined method `new' for SimpleCal:Module (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
        from ./cli.rb:54:in `<main>'
```

Thanks for helping (I'm a newbie)

Comment: Yep, as pointed out by matthewd, this code can't raise this error. Note that by default current dir is not in the $LOAD_PATH, so your SimpleCal.rb won't be found by `require`. If it doesn't crash at require, then it means that it finds __another__ file with this name, elsewhere.

Comment: JFYI, ruby naming convention says that for class SimpleCal, filename should be simple_cal.rb. We like our PascalCase only in class/module names. Most everywhere else it's snake_case.

Comment: Your title contradicts your post (which error is it?) and they both contradict your code (which can't raise them)

Comment: Now I have changed the filename as "simple_cal.rb" and class name as SimpleCal..When I try to require 'simple_cal', I'm getting error "C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- simple_cal (LoadEr
ror)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from ./cli.rb:2:in `<main>'"

Answer (score 1):

The error says SimpleCal is a module, but the code you've shown defines it as a class.

Check that (you've saved the `SimpleCal.rb` file and) it's pointing at the copy of the file you think it is.

Comment: Yes, both are under the same folder and have also used "require SimpleCal" under cli.rb